# can't make or receive calls or send text messages

Tags: applications

I have an LG tracphone,not long after using was unable to get or make any calls or any text messaging,after looking at apps it looks like some have been force stopped or disabled please help.

Answer (score 1):

If the apps are missing from your phone:
Settings>Apps>All Apps, then scroll down to whichever apps are missing from your app drawer (eg. Phone/Dialer, Messaging). Click on the missing app(s), then in the app info screen, you should be able to enable it.

If the apps are there but you can't use the carrier service: Power off your phone, remove the SIM card (if possible) and then reinsert it in the correct position. Then power on the phone.